# Learning DBT debug dbt_project.yml file [ERROR INVALID]

Tags: path, dbt

I'm trying to follow along with a video tutorial to learn/set up a dbt project. I believe I have the `profiles.yml` and `dbt_project.yml` files configured correctly but I keep getting the error:

```
Using profiles.yml file at /Users/cristinarico/.dbt/profiles.yml
Using dbt_project.yml file at /Users/cristinarico/Desktop/learn_dbt/learn-dbt/dbt_project.yml

Configuration:
  profiles.yml file [OK found and valid]
  dbt_project.yml file [ERROR invalid]

Required dependencies:
 - git [OK found]

Connection:
  account: yk74360.us-east-2
  user: transform_user
  database: ANALYTICS
  schema: DBT
  warehouse: TRANSFORM_WH
  role: TRANSFORM_ROLE
  client_session_keep_alive: False
  Connection test: [ERROR]

2 checks failed:
Project loading failed for the following reason:
**Runtime Error
  at path ['name']: 'i-learn-dbt' does not match '^[^\\d\\W]\\w*$'**

Error encountered in /Users/cristinarico/Desktop/learn_dbt/learn-dbt/dbt_project.yml
```

I'm more concerned with the funky path name error than with the snowflake connection at the moment. where is this gibberish (regex?) coming from and why.

[profile.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNWvu.png)
[dbt_project.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyaxG.png)

Answer (score 4):

In the comments on line 1 of the `dbt_project.yml`, it says that the project name should include only lowercase characters and underscores.

Try renaming the project following those guidelines?

Comment: Now that I think of it, the regex might be checking for exactly that, or something related.

Comment: Thank you so much! thats exactly what it was. what is weird is that the tutorial i was watching had dashes which is why i used dashes. So strange!

Comment: Hi @Christina, I think it must be that in a previous version of dbt Core, hyphens were allowed; and the training video was made at that time. Can please you link me to the video and/or code example where hyphens are used?

Comment: And I'm glad that solved your problem! If you liked my answer, please upvote and accept it.